# display UNCLAIMED HD Graphics 630

Tags: drivers, graphics, multiple-monitors, display

I updated from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 LTS a while ago, and I got "display UNCLAIMED".

[image: display UNCLAIMED image link]

but everything else seems working, so I just ignored it. Until now I added a second monitor, There's no options in the display settings

[image: Unknown display image link]

I searched on Google, and tried everything I can find. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: From a google  looks like it might be a driver issue with the graphics card. Can you see which drivers and card you have installed?

Comment: @bob1 thanks for comment, it's "Intel Corporation HD Graphics 630". I searched its drivers already, can't find anything that works.

Comment: I have the exact same issue with the 630 and my HDMI disappearing after an update. Did you find a solution ?

Comment: @Wiper It's been a while, I can't really remember. I think it was not the driver, but some minor issue.